# create an Object and NIL value

Tags: iphone, ios

I am used to have this in my code

**myClass.h**

```
@property ( strong, nonatomic ) ClassA *varA
```

**myClass.m**

```
varA  = [[ClassA alloc] init];
if ( varA isEqual:nil )
   NSLog@"var A is nil");
else
   NSLog@"var A is not nil");
```

this is a result from console

```
var A is not nil
```

I thought var A should be nil then. So my question is what does blue line do and why var A is not nil after all

Comment: Show us your actual code please.

Comment: after you have allocated it should'n be nil right?.

Comment: when init varA, varA is kind of ClassA. before init varA is nil, after , varA is a object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just allocated varA, then you have a ClassA object, you didn't release it or setting it to nil, so why did you expect it to be nil?

It's normal behaviour, it's like you just made (alloc) yourself a nice cup of coffee, if you didn't drink/throw (release or setting it to nil) your coffee should still be there, right?

Comment: yeah your sentences make sense to me now. However, in iOS 5, how and when ARC will release our variables.

Comment: because you're manually creating the object (alloc) yourself, it will be gone when you do varA = nil;

Answer (score 0):

So, nope the nil value is gone right after you allocate the object in a memory space, also you set the values of the ivars to something in the calling for the `init` method in which you probably call a `[super init];` or something similar so you can get the features of the father object.

Hopefully this answers your question.